# QMLE and Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, sandwich, quasi-maximum-likelihood

In the setting of Huber's paper, the true density is $y\sim f_0$, and the density under consideration is $y\sim f(\cdot|\theta)$. If we choose to maximize $y\sim f(\cdot|\theta)$, we will find that $\hat{\theta}\rightarrow \theta_0$, which is the parameter which will minimize the KL divergence between the postulated density to the target density $f_0$. Asymptotic normality for $\hat{\theta}$ may be established with a sandwich variance-covariance.

$$
\hat{\theta}-\theta_0\sim N(0,A^{-1}BA^{-1})
$$

From this I may form confidence intervals from $\hat{\theta}$, but that confidence interval I am forming is actually concerned with capturing $\theta_0$, and not $\theta$ which was originally of interest. If this is the correct interpretation, would it be hard to verify the coverage properties of the sandwich variance estimator in general, since I would need $\theta_0$?

Reference: Freedman, On The So-Called “Huber Sandwich Estimator” and “Robust Standard Errors”